# Сортировка вершин для триангуляции "Обрезкой ушей"

Tags: математика, геометрия

У меня есть триангулированная 3д модель с дырой либо дырами в результате разрезания модели плоскостью(дыры образуют многоугольники), есть координаты всех граничных вершин, как правильно отсортировать вершины что бы получить из них правильный порядок вершин для триангуляции методом обрезки ушей(зашить дыру/дыры)?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Из этой структуры дыры извлекаются без сортировки: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_connected_edge_list.